# Printing source code on Windows

Tags: windows, printing

What is the best Windows program to print out source code (more generally, text files)?  I'd like the following features:

1. Includes line numbers
2. Option of printing 2 or 4 pages on a single sheet of paper.
3. Header includes filename and timestamp.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) is an excellent tool for this (and it's *free*!).  You can print the code out both in normal text, as well as marked-up with colour as you see it on the screen!

Comment: I like Notepad++ (when I'm not using emacs).  I don't see the option for printing up marked-up code though or for including page numbers in the printout.  Where do I look?

Comment: Settings -> Preferences -> Print - Color and Margin

Check "Print Line Number".  Code is printed in colour by default - select a language at the top, and print preview it. :)

Comment: Notepad2 is as powerful as Notepad++, AND tiny AND portable.

Comment: @iDevelop Not even close.  It doesn't have a multiple document interface, a direct side-by-side comparison feature, a plugin manager, and a lot more.  And last I checked, Notepad++ is portable as well.

Comment: notepad++ sucks for printing. It has the basics (syntax hilighting, line-numbering), but that's all. No font setting, no 2-up options, no watermiarking

Comment: @Otheus see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578057/how-to-pretty-print-vba-code/6536863#6536863); of course Np++ doesn't have these features out of the box, but you can easily import the marked up code into Word (or LibreOffice).

Comment: I Use Notepad++ and NppExport plugin. After opening my source_code.cs file I click on Plugins -> NppExport -> Export to RTF. I prefer RTF rather than HTML because lines wrap correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the suggested Notepad++ and Codex, but I find them too limiting.
I could not print two columns per sheet in either one of them.
I like to maximize the amount of code per sheet.
A decade ago I would use pcps to print multiple columns of source code, but that software is just too old and cumbersome in this day and age.
For now, I would suggest this, if you want multi column output: http://www.lerup.com/printfile/

Comment: Actually works pretty well (2014).

Answer (score 2):

UltraEdit works pretty well for all three of those.

[www.ultraedit.com](http://www.ultraedit.com)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Context](http://contexteditor.org/) for most of my non-Visual Studio development, and it does what you asked for and is free.  I don't know how well it does color, but the source code colors print in a couple of varying boldnesses, which makes it pretty readable in black and white.

I just use the printer dialog to set the multi-pages per sheet option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Codex: http://www.snapfiles.com/get/codex.html

Works pretty good, can both print and publish (export to HTML).

Comment: Codex does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[Crimson Editor](http://www.crimsoneditor.com/) looks great too!