# Print Excel VBA code in Word with same color

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, syntax-highlighting, pretty-print

Is it possible to export my VBA code into Microsoft Word in order to print it. Is there a way to keep the same color formatting? I can copy/paste it, but i must select and change the text-color every single time for all the lines (it's long!).

- Is there a tricky way to keep the color formatting?
- Is there a software that I can paste the code into it and just print it.

I wonder how the pros do it...

Comment: Take a look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578057/how-to-pretty-print-vba-code

Answer (score 2):

If you don't fancy installing anything, you could try https://tohtml.com/vbasic/ which I just found.

Copy and paste all your code into the box, press 'Highlight', and copy and paste the result from the preview area.

Comment: Good link. Thanks !